# Why do the C# Managed Functions for my Azure Static Web App return 503 "Function host is not running."

Tags: c#, azure-functions

When deploying an Azure Static Web App with a C# Managed Functions backend (this is the in-the-box functions, as opposed to [Bring Your Own Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-functions)), the functions return 503 and:

```
Function host is not running.
```

Answer (score 2):

After working with Microsoft support, we identified that the referenced NuGet package: [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid@2.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid/2.1.0) was causing this.

This is interesting as the package was *not* being used in the codebase.  It was purely referenced in the `.csproj`:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid" Version="2.1.0" />
```

Simply being there, was enough to prevent Managed Functions for Azure Static Web Apps from working. It's unknown at present, why this is an issue. But there seem to be limitations on Managed Functions for Azure Static Web Apps.